# JOOQ CodeGen: does not generate Java code for Oracle Synonyms

Tags: jooq

Setup:

- `JOOQ 3.13.1 Professional`
- `dialect ORACLE12C`

We have 2 synonyms pointing to different tables.

synonyms:
`TAB_CONFIGURATION`     points to a table (TAB_.._01 ... TAB_.._08)
`TAB_CONFIGURATION_NEXT`    points to a table (TAB_.._01 ... TAB_.._08)

tables:
`TAB_CONFIGURATION_01`
..
`TAB_CONFIGURATION_08`

The JOOQ code generator does not generate any Java classes for the 2 synonyms (only for the 8 tables). I've no idea why not.

Can the JOOQ code generator process Oracle synonyms at all?

Answer (score 2):

#### Synonyms are not supported yet in this way, as of jOOQ 3.13

This would be a useful feature indeed, however, it is not yet implemented in jOOQ as of 3.13: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1563.

Oracle doesn't report synonyms as ordinary tables through dictionary views like `SYS.ALL_TABLES` or `SYS.ALL_TAB_COLS`, hence it is not so easy to discover synonyms like ordinary tables, including:

- Table information
- Column information
- Constraint information

All of this information needs to be discovered by recursively traversing the graph exposed in `SYS.ALL_SYNONYMS`.

However, as of jOOQ 3.13, `SYS.ALL_SYNONYMS` is being introspected when procedures / packages reference data types via synonyms, in case of which the synonyms are resolved to the actual data type.

#### Workaround: Views

You can use views instead of synonyms. For most use-cases, this works exactly the same way, to alias tables.

So, if you have:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab_configuration_01 (...);
CREATE TABLE tab_configuration_02 (...);
...
CREATE TABLE tab_configuration_08 (...);
```

Instead of defining:

```sql
CREATE SYNONYM tab_configuration FOR tab_configuration_02;
CREATE SYNONYM tab_configuration_next FOR tab_configuration_03;
```

You could also define:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_configuration AS SELECT * FROM tab_configuration_02;
CREATE VIEW view_configuration_next AS SELECT * FROM tab_configuration_03;
```

This already works out of the box in jOOQ. Advantage: You can access both the actual tables with the numeric suffix, if you want, or the view. You can update the view definition in the database without having to change your client code, i.e. without regenerating it (assuming all your tables are the same).

#### Workaround: jOOQ's generator strategy

You can define the generated class names and identifier names using "generator strategies":

- [Programmatically](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/)
- [Configuratively](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/)

For example:

```xml
<generator>
  <strategy>
    <matchers>
      <tables>
        <table>
          <expression>TAB_CONFIGURATION_02</expression>
          <tableClass>
            <transform>PASCAL</transform>
            <expression>TAB_CONFIGURATION</expression>
          </tableClass>
          <tableIdentifier>
            <transform>AS_IS</transform>
            <expression>TAB_CONFIGURATION</expression>
          </tableIdentifier>
        </table>
        <table>
          <expression>TAB_CONFIGURATION_03</expression>
          <tableClass>
            <transform>PASCAL</transform>
            <expression>TAB_CONFIGURATION_NEXT</expression>
          </tableClass>
          <tableIdentifier>
            <transform>AS_IS</transform>
            <expression>TAB_CONFIGURATION_NEXT</expression>
          </tableIdentifier>
        </table>
      </tables>
    </matchers>
  </strategy>
</generator>
```

Advantage: You don't need a new database object for your "synonym". But you can no longer reference the original numeric-suffixed tables from client code, because they may be renamed to something else. Also, you have to re-generate your jOOQ code every time you want to change the "synonym".